# Error in ggplot.data.frame : Mapping should be created with aes or aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, zoo

I am having a trouble while extracting the path from a `ggplot` and am stuck with an error.

The image given below explains the result I am looking for: (Done in image editor for explaining purpose)

[image]

Let's assume that Plot 1 is my original plot. What I am looking for is taking first point as 'F' point and traveling 24hrs from that point.

```
Des %>%
   mutate(nf = cumsum(ACT=="F")) %>%  # build F-to-F groups
group_by(nf) %>%
mutate(first24h = as.numeric((DateTime-min(DateTime)) < (24*3600))) %>% # find the first 24h of each F-group
ggplot(aes(x=Loq, y=Las)) + 
geom_path(aes(colour=first24h)) + scale_size(range = c(1, 2))+ geom_point()

Library(zoo)
full.time = seq(Des$DateTime[1], tail(Des$DateTime, 1), by=600)   # new timeline with point at every 10 min
d.zoo = zoo(Des[,2:3], Des$DateTime)        # convert to zoo object
d.full = as.data.frame(na.approx(d.zoo, xout=full.time))  # interpolate; result is also a zoo object
d.full$DateTime = as.POSIXct(rownames(d.full))
```

*When I am using `na.approx` for interpolation it is giving me Error??* Otherwise not.

> Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : 
>       need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In xy.coords(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion

With these two `data.frame`s combined. Every F-F section is drawn in a separate plot and only the points not longer than 24h after the F-point is shown

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

Des %>%
  select(ACT, DateTime) %>%
  right_join(d.full, by="DateTime") %>%
  mutate(ACT = ifelse(is.na(ACT),"",ACT)) %>%
  mutate(nf = cumsum(ACT=="F")) %>%
  group_by(nf) %>%
  mutate(first24h = (DateTime-min(DateTime)) < (24*3600)) %>%
  filter(first24h == TRUE) %>%
  filter(first24h == 1) %>%
  ggplot(Des, aes(x=Loq, y=Las,colour=ACT)) +
  geom_path() + facet_wrap(~ nf)
```

**Error**

> Error in ggplot.data.frame(., Des, aes(x = Loq, y = Las, colour = ACT)) : 
>       Mapping should be created with aes or aes_string

This is my `Des` format:

```
ID  Las  Loq  ACT  Time  Date
1  12    13   R  23:20 1-1-01
1  13    12   F  23:40 1-1-01
1  13    11   F  00:00 2-1-01
1  15    10   R  00:20 2-1-01
1  12    06   W  00:40 2-1-01
1  11    09   F  01:00 2-1-01
1  12    10   R  01:20 2-1-01
so on...
```

Comment: Try taking `Data` out of your call to `ggplot`. Since you're using the pipe, the data argument is assumed and your first argument should be the `aes`.  Or you can remove the pipe operator before `ggplot`.

Comment: @Benjamin Can you please paste the command here. I tried to take the Data out initially then it show me the Error: `Loq not found`

Comment: Try to replace `Data` with a `.`

Comment: @Jaap `Error in inherits(mapping, "uneval") : object 'Des.' not found`

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(Des)` or `dput(Des[sample(nrow(Des), 20),])` in your question?

Comment: You can also [make up some data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Follow the link to see some examples on how to do that.

Comment: Furthermore, your `ggplot` code should probably start with: `ggplot(. , aes(x=Loq, y=Las,colour=ACT))`

Comment: @Jaap I do have a structure ready with me. and I have successfully implemented the same code which I have posted here. However, when I am applying this code in the original dataset it is producing errors

Answer (score 7):

The error (in the title of the post) arises because you have too many arguments to `ggplot`. As the comments to the question note, the pipeline `%>%` implicitly includes the output from the left-hand side of the pipe as the first argument to the function on the righthand side.

```
# these have the same meaning
f(x, y)
x %>% f(y)
```

This code replicates the same kind of error. (I've separated out the `aes` mapping to its own step for clarity.)

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(am == 1) %>% 
  ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x = mpg, y = wt) + 
  geom_point()
#> Error in ggplot.data.frame(., mtcars) : 
#>   Mapping should be created with aes or aes_string
```

Conceptually--if you "unpipe" things--what's being executed is the something like following:

```
ggplot(filter(mtcars, am == 1), mtcars)
```

The `ggplot` function assumes the first argument is the `data` parameter and the second is an `aes` aesthetic mapping. But in your pipeline, the first two arguments are data frames. This is the source of the error.

The solution is to remove the redundant data argument. More generally, I separate my data transformation pipeline (`%>%` chains) from my `ggplot` plot building (`+` chains).

Answer (score 0):

```
Des %>%
   mutate(nf = cumsum(ACT=="F")) %>%  # build F-to-F groups
   group_by(nf) %>%
   mutate(first24h = as.numeric((DateTime-min(DateTime)) < (24*3600))) %>% # find the first 24h of each F-group
   ggplot(., aes(x=Loq, y=Las)) + 
   geom_path(aes(colour=first24h)) + scale_size(range = c(1, 2))+ geom_point()
```

At the point: ggplot(., aes(x=Loq, y=Las)) - use '.' to refer to the data as you cant double up

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.