# ggplot2 & spline() in R - Error in : `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

Reproducible example for data generation:

```
n <- 9
x <- 1:n
y <- rnorm(n)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I know how to plot data with a spline without ggplot2.

```
plot(x, y, main = paste("spline[fun](.) "))
lines(spline(x, y))
```

plot image available here :

[image]

However, **I want to plot a spline with ggplot2**. Here is a code example:

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(spline(data))
```

The error I get is:
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Same error gets thrown if I use

```
ggplot(aes(data, x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(spline(data))
```

or

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(spline(x, y))
```

or

```
ggplot(aes(x = data$x, y = data$y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(spline(data$x,data$y))
```

The following one gives different error. It was explored in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892644/error-in-ggplot-data-frame-mapping-should-be-created-with-aes-or-aes-string), but I want to plot a spline and am not sure how to apply the solution to my situation.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(spline(x, y))
```

Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way to do that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = data.frame(spline(x, y))) #+
  #ggthemes::theme_base()
```

[image: 54942745]

The problem is: `spline` returns `list`, you just should have convert it  into `data.frame` and that's it.